# Kafka Connect Sink Lag

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka Connect Sink writing records from a Kafka topic to S3. It's working, but it's too slow. The Kafka topic receives ~30k msg/sec. The Connect Sink isn't able to keep up. I've tried increasing the Kafka Connector `tasks.max` from 1 to 3, that created more tasks, but that didn't seem to help improve the msg/sec speed. I've tried increasing the Kafka Connect workers CPU allotment, that didn't seem to help either.

What else can I try? What metrics would be useful to monitor to further identify the bottleneck?

UPDATE: the Kafka topic has 5 partitions. The Kafka cluster has 5 broker servers. Kafka Connect is running in a Kubernetes cluster and is using the latest Confluent Kafka Connect 5.4.0. The Kafka brokers are running a much older version.

Comment: How many partitions does your Kafka topic have?

Comment: The Kafka topic has 5 partitions. The Kafka cluster also has 5 broker servers.

Comment: How many connect workers do you have?

Comment: Kafka Connect is running 5 worker replicas. I recently boosted from 3 and that didn't seem to improve anything.

Comment: When you increase the number of tasks, do you observe them running across the workers, one per worker?

Comment: 3 worker replicas seem to be using near zero CPU. The other two are running at 5-10% CPU capacity, so active but not CPU bound at all.

Comment: Right, but what about my question? ;) Which workers are executing the tasks? You can use the Kafka Connect REST API to check.

Comment: With 3 tasks, I see two tasks running on a single worker, and a third task running on a separate worker. Why would that be?

Comment: Hi Clay, I am facing the same issue, did u find any solution for this issue?

Comment: In my case, the issue was network bandwidth. When we upgraded the network connection, the problem went away. Some of the Kafka Connect metrics tell you how long the connect workers are waiting on I/O, but I forget which precise ones.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I see that it was a network bandwidth problem.

But to get visibility on that, you can use the JMX metrics of kafka-connect

```yaml
domain: kafka.connect
    type: sink-task-metrics
    attribute:
        - sink-record-send-rate 
        - put-batch-avg-time-ms

domain: kafka.consumer
    type: consumer-fetch-manager-metrics
    attribute:
        - records-per-request-avg
```